# Fix Safari Loading Iframe Zoomed In

Tags: html, css, safari

EDIT: Simplified the question:

I have a 100% width "seamless" `iframe` in which I embed another (local) page.

When accessing the page directly on Safari, the contents are properly zoomed out to fit the screen.
However when the website is in an `iframe`, the page loads zoomed in and I have to zoom out manually in order to see it in full width. Is there a workaround for this?

Iframe code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>iFrame</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <style>
            body, html, iframe
            {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            iframe
            {
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <iframe src="index.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you be willing to provide some code?

Comment: @Maximilian added code.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue locally. Have you tried setting the width and height to 100vh, 100vw?

Comment: @Maximilian e.g. try to load this site via iframe e.g.: http://superior-web-solutions.com/

Comment: Still not able to reproduce the error locally, the site you suggested loads as it should? Do you mean that if you make the window smaller the page isn't zoomed out? If that is the case, it's not possible to achieve as iframes are rendered at 100%